# Calculate total sales without missing values while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms

I have a query

I have to calculate monthly sales per branch and customer (Data coming from one table)

Data should look like below

[image]

I can write the query for Jan_2019 total sales:

I create a temp table for Feb_2019. I can use the join and combine the 2 tables, but in Feb_2019 if there are new customers added, then when joining the tables I am missing new customers, and due to this the total sales for that month are not matching.

Can any one help?

I have written the query like this below

```
;with a as
(
select branchid, customer, sum(totalsales) as jan_totalsales from tableA
where year = 2019 and month = 1
group by customer, branched
), feb as

(
select branchid, customer, sum(totalsales) as feb_totalsales  from tableA
where year = 2019 and month = 2
group by customer, branched
)
select a.branchid, feb.branchid, a.jan_totalsales, feb.feb_totalsales
 from a
left join feb on feb.branchid = a.branchid
```

I have to create this in a temp table and do it for march_2019

Again, I am not getting new customers as I am joining from Jan data.

Can anyone help me to make this simple?

Comment: MySQL and SQL-Server are 2 completely different RDBMS, which are you really using. Considering you've tagged SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) I ***assume*** the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after here is a conditional aggregate. This *should* get you on the right path:

```
SELECT branchid,
       customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2019] AND [Month] = 1 THEN totalsales ELSE 0 END) AS JanSales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2019] AND [Month] = 2 THEN totalsales ELSE 0 END) AS FebSales,
       ....
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY branchid,
         customer;
```

If you don't undertstand how this works, please do ask. At the end of the day, it's you who has to support the SQL, not myself or other volunteers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Worked fine. Thank You.